# Prove $2016^{2017} + 2018^{2017} + (2015)!! + (2016)!!$ is divisible by $2017$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The task is to prove $2017$ divides $2016^{2017} + 2018^{2017} + (2015)!! + (2016)!!$.

Since $2017$ is a prime Fermat's little theorem is applicable. The part I am struggling with is the double factorial. Wilson's theorem is of no help and I can't seem to expand/multiply this expression with any factor to get something I could work with.

Any guidelines?

---

Edit: As shown by the user Especially Lime, $2017$ does not divide given expression.

Comment: Wilson's theorem?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown
If p is a prime, then p divides (p-1)! + 1.

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: is double factorial $n!!=n\cdot (n-2)\cdot(n-4)\cdots$?

Comment: Note, $2016^{2017}+2018^{2017}\equiv(-1)^{2017}+1^{2017}\equiv0$ mod $2017$ because $2017$ is *odd*, not because it's prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the double factorial $2015!!$ means $2015\times2013\times\cdots\times 1$ and $2016!!$ is $2016\times2014\times\cdots\times2$. In that case, note that 
$$2015\times2013\times\cdots\times 1\equiv(-2)\times(-4)\times\cdots\times(-2016)$$
(mod $2017$).

Comment: There's an even number of minus signs on the right, so it looks to me like this says $2017$ does *not* divide the sum.

Comment: @BarryCipra You're right, well spotted! I just assumed it must be an odd number. I've just used python to calculate $2016!!$ and $2015!!$ (mod $2017$) as a check, and they're both congruent to $229$, so there must be a mistake in the question.

Answer (score 3):

the statement is not true

infact for FLT it easily to check that the sum of the first 2 terms is $\equiv 0$ (mod 2017)

for the last two terms let's indicate with

$a=2015!!$ and $b=2016!!$

as shown by"Expecially Lime": $a \equiv b$ (mod 2017)

and also: $ab=2016! \equiv -1$ for WT

thus $a^2 \equiv b^2 \equiv -1$ (mod 2017)

then a+b $\not\equiv 0$ (mod 2017)

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that the analogous expression, $2012^{2013}+2014^{2013}+(2011)!!+(2012)!!$ **is** divisible by $2013$, precisely because $2013$ is **not** prime!

Comment: because $2012^{2013}+2014^{2013} \equiv (-1)^{2013}+1^{2013} \equiv 0$ and $2011!! =2011...671...3 \times 1$ and $2012!! =2^{1006}*1006=2^{1006}*1006...671...3 \times 2 \times 1$ I guess :)

Comment: Yes, exactly! ${\\\\\\}$